# How Many Different $2$-Course Dinners are Possible?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I got this question on combinatorics, but I am very confused about it.

Q: A restaurant has a choice of $12$ main courses and $4$ desserts. How many $2$-course dinner selections are from the menu?

I assume the answer is $2\times4\times12$

Comment: What's the approach you took?

Comment: Any thoughts?  If you are confused, a good place to start is with smaller collections.  Say $3$ main courses and $2$ desserts.

Comment: A 2-course dinner consists of one main course and one dessert, I assume. So the question is how many different pairings of main courses and desserts can you have?

Comment: Pick a main course. Then pick a dessert. How many distinct pairs (main, dessert) are possible?

Comment: Your answer relies on the assumption that choosing a main course followed by a dessert is different from choosing a dessert followed by a main course. This *could* be true mathematically, but common sense dictates that the two are equivalent, since you're always going to eat your dessert after your main course.

Comment: Suppose there is $1$ main course and $1$ dessert.  Do you believe that there are two $2-$ course selections?  What are they?

Comment: If you would violate social norms by eating dessert first, I presume you might also order 2 main courses or 2 desserts, in which case you have 16 x 16 choices.  I htink you were intended to abide by social norms.

Answer (score 0):

If a 2-course dinner consists of one main course and one dessert, then since there are twelve choices for the main course and four choices for the dessert, there are $(12)(4) = 48$ different possible 2-course dinners.